# Cannot create custom theme in ggplot2 - keeps giving unused arguments error

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I keep getting an unused arguments error when I try to build a custom theme in ggplot2 and I can't figure out where the problem lies. When I run this code:

```
theme_custom <- theme(
  text = element_text(
    family = 'serif',
    size = 14),
  rect = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  title = element_text(color = 'black'),
  axis.line = element_line(color = 'black')
  )
```

I get an error:

```
Error in theme(text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 14), rect = element_blank(),  : 
  unused arguments (text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 14), rect = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(), title = element_text(color = "black"), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))
```

I tried adapting an existing theme (played around with slightly different customisations here, please excuse) but still kept getting the unused arguments error. I've checked the help file for the theme() function and cannot see any errors with the below arguments.

```
font <- "serif"

theme_custom <- function(){
  theme_classic() %+replace%
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(
        family = font,
        size = 14,
        hjust = 0,
        vjust = 2),
      axis.title = element_text(
        family = font,
        size = 14),
      axis.text = element_text(
        family = font,
        size = 14)
    )}
```

The error happens when I run the code to assign the theme to the theme_custom object but just in case, this is the graph I'm looking to build:

```
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x_var, y = m_var,group=region)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=region), size=4) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=10, linetype="dashed", color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=6, linetype="dashed", color = "black") +
  labs(x="X variable", y="Y variable", title="Graph 1") + 
  xlim(0, 15) +
  ylim(0, 20) +
  theme_custom()
```

Comment: This sounds like you may have a conflict with a `theme()` function from another package. If you run `conflicts()`, does `"theme"` show up in the results? Does your code work if you specify `theme_custom <- ggplot2::theme(...)`?

Comment: I tried today and theme didn't show up as a conflict but using ggplot2::theme has now resolved the issue, thank you!